# NET::ERR_CERT_DATE_INVALID error in Chrome when browsing python.org or github.com

Tags: google-chrome, ssl

Since one of the latest chrome updates, I'm getting this error that does not allow me to access some webs such as python.org or github.com. I've googled the problem but they say that it is generated when the system clock is out of sync. I've checked it and it is perfectly in sync ( i've even used different NTP servers apple, windows, ntp.org, etc...)

I don't have this problem with other browsers in the same computer, neither with the same chrome version in other computers in the same network.

I've even tried to reinstall chrome from scratch without success.

There are no proxies , nor firewalls in the computer.

Any ideas?

Comment: I am having the exact same problem

Answer (score 0):

See [Can AVG 2015's Online Shield be used Chrome (and not give NET::ERR_CERT_DATE_INVALID)?](https://superuser.com/questions/897452/can-avg-2015s-online-shield-be-used-chrome-and-not-give-neterr-cert-date-inv) for a possible solution: *disable `Online Shield` on your AVG `firewall`* (or the equivalent component - that scans files before they're downloaded - on the anti-virus you use).