# Can AVG 2015's Online Shield be used Chrome (and not give NET::ERR_CERT_DATE_INVALID)?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, certificate, ssl-certificate, avg-antivirus

I am using AVG 2015.  If I enable Online Shield, websites that use some of Google's API's (including StackExchange sites) become unavailable and start displaying a `NET::ERR_CERT_DATE_INVALID` error within Chrome.

Is there a way to use AVG 2015's Online Shield feature within Chrome?

**Environment:**

- Windows 7 SP1
- AVG Internet Security 2015
- Google Chrome 41.0.2272.118 m

Comment: Besides the fact Online Shield basically makes every secure connection insecure, that particular error, cannot be fixed by you as the end user only AVG.

Comment: I should provide some additional information.  Unless you stop using Chrome, Chrome will continue to detect, your security software is performing a MiTM attack on your secure connection.  I will repeat that enabling Online Shield is a horrible idea, all traffic to any secure website, can be viewed by your security software and that information  in theory could be sent to AVG.

Comment: Thanks  @Ramhound: I guess I'll have to learn to live with the AVG "You are not fully protected" warning.